# How to set different countdown timer to different labels of collectionviewcell in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on an application where I have to get seconds left in event (Which is different for all the events) and then I have to print the countdown time (i.e time left) for event in each collectionviewcell.Number of rows here are 5 for suppose.

```
- (col *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";col *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];  
secondsLeft= seconds left depending on data which I can get successfully;

[self start];
cell.lbl_time.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
return cell;}   -(void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer{
if(secondsLeft > 0 ) {
secondsLeft -- ;
hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
//count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Timer Invalidate");
  //  [timer invalidate];
}}    -(void)start{
timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];}
```

Let me know what I should do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code could be little better formatted. And for solution I am not sure why you want more timers. I would have one in which I would reload collectionView (`[self.collectionView reloadData];`) and each cell would calculate time left. There is no need for multiple timers (if I understand your problem correctly).

Comment: Thanks for replying.
What I want is to display timer according to seconds left for event on label which is in collectionviewcell class.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can make the reference of the label you want to update in the collectionViewCell in the viewController, or
2. You can make a separate model for CollectionViewCell and update the model from ViewController and call reload method of collectionView.